# Texts not aligning even if I use the "align-items" property to center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I cant seem to get the nav bar items to align to the center even if I set the align-items value to center, I cant seem to find any part of code which commands the nav bar items to stick to the right either!

I need a solution to this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
} 

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 50px 0 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav .logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #111;
  background: #fff;
}

nav .menu-btn i{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav{
    padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  nav .menu-btn i{
    display: block;
  }
  
  #click:checked ~ .menu-btn i:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    background: #111;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul {
    left: 0;
  }
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul li a {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: cyan;
  }
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #1b1b1b;
}

.content div {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

That's my CSS code, I tried to do what I could but I cant fix the problem

Comment: Please provide your html codes so we can check!

Answer (score 0):

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: center;
```

justify-content: flex-end; = inserts elements to the right x-axis position.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the justify-content but it still dosen't seem to work!

Answer (score -2):

first of all to make it horizontally center you need to make the justify-content:center not the align-items

your code should be

```css
nav{
/*...*/
justify-content:center;
/*...*/
}
```